# Validate Textboxes in a WPF Program without Button Event like Excel

Tags: c#, wpf

For example i have 3 textboxes B1, B2 & B3. 
B3 = B1 + B2;
I was looking for a way to Display B3 as soon as i type something in B1 or B2 like in Excel.
The only solution i know would be with a button click but that is not what i am looking for.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add `TextChanged` event handlers for textboxes `B1` and `B2` so we can recalculate sum of their values in textbox `B3` when `B1` or `B2` has been changed.

In `.xaml` file i have simple grid with 3 textboxes:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="B1" Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Height="40" TextChanged="B1_OnTextChanged"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="B2" Grid.Row="1" Width="100" Height="40" TextChanged="B2_OnTextChanged"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="B3" Grid.Row="2" Width="100" Height="40"/>
</Grid>
```

When `B1` or `B2` text is changed i call `calculateB1B2()` method to set `Text` property for `B3` textbox.

```
private void B1_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    calculateB1B2();
}

private void B2_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    calculateB1B2();
}

private void calculateB1B2()
{
    if (double.TryParse(B1.Text, out var b1)
        && double.TryParse(B2.Text, out var b2))
    {
        B3.Text = $"{b1 + b2}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, do this at the `YourForm_Load`:

`textBox3.Visible = false;` or instead just set it to `false` in the `[Designer]`

Put this into the `TextChanged` of the `TextBox1` & `TextBox2`:

`textBox3.Visible = true;`

Change the control names as needed.

- If you are looking to also update B3's text as well, then do this in B1 or B2's `TextChanged`:

`textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text`

I hope it helps :)